Why is Epsilon Indi Ab 2° Celsius?
I was reading the Wikipedia page for the exoplanet Epsilon Indi Ab.
It orbits around its parent star every 173.6 years in a distance of 28.4 AU as provided in the first infobox of the article.
The parent star is in fact a star system consisting of three stars called Epsilon Indi. The stars are Epsilon Indi A, Ba, and Bb respectively.
Epsilon Indi A, the star that the mentioned exoplanet revolves around has a surface temperature of only 4649 K which makes it even colder than our Sun.
My question: How does an exoplanet orbiting around a cold star at such a huge distance have a temperature of near 275 K?

It's because it is a gas giant (arguably it should be called a brown dwarf) and its temperature is not governed by the radiation it passively receives from the star it orbits. The heat is generated by gravitational contraction - an ongoing process since the planet was "born". Half the gravitational potential energy released by contraction goes into heating the planet/brown dwarf and half is lost as radiation into space.
Indeed, as the Wikipedia article mentions, there are isolated Y-type brown dwarfs that have a similar temperature, and for the same reason. See for example https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/8128/2531 and the plot below which shows the cooling history as a function of mass (adapted from Burrows 1997 by Philip Muirhead).


Why doesn't Jupiter have this own temperature while it's also a gas giant?

@SnackExchange it does. Jupiter radiates more energy than it receives from the Sun. But a lower mass gas giant cools more quickly.
